# Google Closure Compiler warns with JSC_CONSTANT_REASSIGNED_VALUE_ERROR on let declarations

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, google-closure-compiler

I'm using Google Closure Compiler to minify the following code:

```
{
  let x = 10,
      y = 20;
  console.log(y);
}

{
  let x = 30,
      y = 40;
  console.log(y);
}
```

(See also [this link](https://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home#code%3D%252F%252F%2520%253D%253DClosureCompiler%253D%253D%250A%252F%252F%2520%2540compilation_level%2520SIMPLE_OPTIMIZATIONS%250A%252F%252F%2520%2540output_file_name%2520default.js%250A%252F%252F%2520%253D%253D%252FClosureCompiler%253D%253D%250A%250A%252F%252F%2520ADD%2520YOUR%2520CODE%2520HERE%250A%257B%250A%2520%2520let%2520x%2520%253D%252010%252C%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520y%2520%253D%252020%253B%250A%2520%2520console.log(y)%253B%250A%257D%250A%2520%2520%250A%257B%250A%2520%2520let%2520x%2520%253D%252030%252C%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520y%2520%253D%252040%253B%250A%2520%2520console.log(y)%253B%250A%257D%250A) to the Closure Compiler web app.)

Inexplicably to me, the compiler gives the following warning:

```
JSC_CONSTANT_REASSIGNED_VALUE_ERROR: constant y assigned a value more than once.
Original definition at Input_0:4 at line 10 character 6
      y = 40;
      ^
```

This raises multiple questions:

- Is anything about these `let` declarations invalid?
- The declarations are wrapped in their own blocks. So they should be independent of each other. Correct?
- Why does it give me this warning?
- Why is the warning only given for `y` and not for `x`?
- Why does it refer to `y` as a "constant"? I never declared a constant anywhere in this snippet.

This is the output code in ES5 syntax:

```
var x=10,y=20;console.log(y);var x$0=30;y=40;console.log(y);
```

Indeed, Google Closure Compiler reuses the `y` variable from the first block. It doesn't do this for `x`, however.

Any ideas what's going on here?

Comment: And what if you do `let x = 10; let y = 20;` and `let x = 30; let y = 40;`

Comment: It appears the compiler treat `y` as a global variable since it doesn't have its own `let` command, and if, that might be a bug.

Comment: You're not doing anything wrong. It's not limited to plain blocks - the same behavior exists with `for` loops. It's an issue with the compiler.

Comment: It works if I give `y` its own `let` command. @CertainPerformance is this a known bug? (I couldn't find this in the ~800 open issues on GitHub.) Will probably file it then. Thanks for the comments!

Comment: It appears there is a bug with transpilation. Please file an issue.

Comment: Done: https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/issues/2969

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was fixed with 
https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/commit/b3146ab187540c5bdf3b24f8ebf6ddede7fd63c5

It is no longer reproducible with the current release (or webservice).